# On stop scrolling auto position column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

i'm working on a split scrolling site with two columns. And it's working great, but there is one problem i can't seem to solve. It's when i stop scrolling and the columns are positioned like this:

[image: example img]

They need to automatically position themselves next to each other, so the user gets to see the full nicely aligned image. Now i've tried using Jquery Inview:

```
$('.content:nth-child(2)').one('inview', function (event, visible) { // i know the selector is wrong just for example purposes
  if (visible == true) {
    $('col.left').css( "top", "0" );
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
  }
});
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick.. Using inview is probably the wrong way to go anyway. Now i have tried googling a solution but i can't seem to be able to find anything that does the trick. Does anyone know a plugin that does this for me? Or if someone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u9apC/2/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call a function to align the left and right after the user has completed scrolling. This example assumes the left and right columns are the same (as in your example).

```
...
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.right').css('top', (top + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(function(){scrollend();},200);
    });

    function scrollend(){
        //console.log("scrollend");
        clearTimeout(t);
        $('.right').css('top', (0 - $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
    }
...
```

E.G: http://jsfiddle.net/u9apC/4/

Comment: In case it's of any use, here's an example which animates the left and right columns into position either up or down depending on the current position: http://jsfiddle.net/46eP2/1/. Brandon Aaron's jquery-mousewheel plugin can be used for completeness: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Comment: Thanks for your example, it doesn't seem to be working :( but ill give it a go :D